# Are there any subspaces U,W of R^7 s.t. dim(U)=4, dim(W)=6, dim(UnW) = 2?

Tags: linear-algebra

Hey I need to prove that this is either possible or not. Given U,W to be subspaces of R^7, can we have dim(U)=4, dim(W)=6, dim(UnW)=2? (Any subspaces that satisfy this?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $U$ and $W$ exist then the subspace $U+W$ of $\Bbb R^7$ has the dimension:
$$\dim(U+W)=\dim U+\dim W-\dim(U\cap W)=8>7=\dim\Bbb R^7$$
which is impossible. Conclude.

Comment: Thanks so much I actually just came up with something equivalent!

Comment: You're welcome.